# Relations of some exponential functions -- which is correct?

Tags: asymptotics

Consider the following functions

- $f(n) = 3n^{(n^{1/2})}  $
- $g(n) = 2^{(n^{1/2}) \log n }$  // here base of $\log n$ is 2
- $h(n) = n !$

Which of the following is true?

1. $ h (n)$ is $O (f (n) )  $
2. $h (n)$ is $O (g (n)) $
3. $g (n)$ is not $O (f (n) )  $
4. $ f(n)$ is $O(g (n))$

I tried this way :

To check which function is large :

$3n^{(n^{1/2})}$ = taking log

$n^{1/2} \log 3n $

$g(n) = 2^{(n^{1/2}) \log n }$

by taking log :

$((n^{1/2})\log n )\log 2$ => $0.3 (n^{1/2})\log n  $

$h(n) = n !$ => $n^n  $

by taking log :

$n \log n $

So now comparing all these 3 functions I got following equality :

$f(n) < g(n) < h(n)  $ 
So answer should be (4) but actually answer is (1).
Could anyone explain me where I am wrong ?

Comment: The answer given in the book could be wrong.

Comment: [This question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth) should contain all you need.

Answer (score 2):

(1) is not the correct answer.  Perhaps there is an error in the book, or an error in what you entered.  As you correctly concluded, $f(n) = 3 e^{n^{1/2} \log n}$ and $h(n) \approx e^{n \log n}$ (by Stirling's approximation), so it is not true that $h(n) = O(f(n))$.

I can't tell whether you've drawn the correct conclusions about the pairwise relationships between these three functions.  You wrote that $f(n) < g(n) < h(n)$, but this is not correct.  For instance, $f(1) = 3$, $g(1) = 3$, $h(1) = 1$.  Those inequalities don't hold for all $n$ -- but if we care about big-O notation, then that's not the right question anyway, since big-O notation relates to the asymptotic behavior of these functions (as $n\to \infty$).

The right question is whether $f(n) = O(g(n))$, whether $g(n) = O(f(n))$ (be careful here!  better double-check your work on this one another time), and so on.

See also [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755) and [How does one know which notation of time complexity analysis to use?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57/755).  They should answer your remaining questions.